# Not showing the android incoming call screen

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to archive the following behavior in my android application: if my application is already running and there is an incoming call the application should stay visible and if possible turn down the call. Thanks all for your time

PS. I've found the same question here: [Can an activity receive an unordered broadcast(incoming call) intent before system's default receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869314/can-an-activity-receive-an-unordered-broadcastincoming-call-intent-before-syst) but when i tried it the app crashes and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You problem seem close to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7121508/1979347. Modify code according to your own need.

Comment: @RohanKandwal Thanks! I will try it and let you know